# LTspice not converging for modified Cockcroft-Walton circuit

Tags: ltspice, simulation, high-voltage

I wanted to simulate modified Cockcroft-Walton circuit(shown in first figure). I simulated and got the results (as shown in the second figure). I made a hierarchical block to use repeatedly but ran into a problem when I started the simulation. It took almost 3-4 hours after which I got a message **not enough disk space**. I poked around to find the .raw file took up **21.4 GB**. I am confused as this problem arises only when I use hierarchical block.

[image: modified cockcroft-walton]
[image: simulation results]
[image: storage]

Comment: Also, the diodes are using a generic simulation part.  If you want to more accurately model a specific diode, right-click them and choose the desired part.  Some diodes will work better than others for this role.

Comment: Try going into the Simulation Control Panel and dork around with the Integration parameters on the SPICE tab.

Comment: @rdtsc yeah I am aware of it but what bothers me is this

Comment: @Sathya_PS [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ughgx.png) how you might both modularize as well as achieve higher voltage from a source. Note that only one subcircuit is needed for both positive and negative rail generation. Just flip it over to go the other way. The price paid for that convenience is that you need to show some external caps. (Frankly, I like the way it looks though.) I'll leave you to read the SUBCKT shown. Then just cascade them as shown. It's a lot easier editing a schematic this way.

Comment: @periblepsis Thanks for the lovely circuit. Myself not a professional so took some time to figure it out. Seems we couldn't get 15KV from 12V after all. A student still learning it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have no ground reference some parts of the circuit, try placing a large value resistor (make the value something like 1E12) from the bottom of L2 to ground, and from the L4 and L6 junction (Vref) to ground. LTspice tends to want to have some sort of path to ground in each part of a circuit, even if it's a very high impedance path.

I think that should solve the convergence problem and once that's solved the large file size will sort itself out as well.

Update: As Kevin White mentioned Vout also has no path to ground, so add a resistor there as well. I also had to add some series resistance to L3 and L5 as my LTspice was complaining about an 'over-defined circuit matrix'. I used 1u\$\Omega\$ on each. I believe this depends on your LTspice setup so you may or may not run into this problem.

Comment: I added two resistors 1E12 to the end of L2 and Vref in the simulation but to no avail. It speeded upto 49% then started dragging. Stopped it in the fear of hanging my system.

Comment: @SathyaNarayan  Usually this works with transformers. Sometimes I put the resistor from primary to secondary. You could also try reducing them to 1E9 or maybe put a small capacitor across them, like 1pF. I'll try to sim it and see what results I get. Also what rdtsc said about the generic diodes, I didn't see that at first. You should pretty much never use the generic diodes and transistors in LTspice.

Comment: You may need a resistor to ground from VOUT as well. It has no direct path to ground.

Comment: @KevinWhite Good catch, that made it work for me.

Comment: @GodJihyo I picked 1N4007 resistor, tried all integration parameters and modified the circuit which is [here](https://imgur.com/a/E8wD390). It is still slow. Can you schematic as an image link.

Answer (score 3):

Your circuit shows three loops and two groups of nets which potentially cause a singular matrix error. Add a small resistance (say 1u) to one of V1 or L1; at least two of L2, L3, L5; and assign a ground reference (at least a large-value (<1G) resistor) to one of the L2-L3-L5 nets, and something on the right side (probably just ground Vout since the intent seems to be a balanced circuit?).

Comment: [here](https://imgur.com/a/E8wD390) is the circuit schematic. Hope I included all your changes

Comment: @Sathya_PS There is still a short circuit between L3, L5; and 1e12 is rather high, 1e9 would be more typical. Or none at all since resistance shouldn't seem to matter for ground reference as yet.

Answer (score 2):

Ground your secondary side somewhere, try K=0.999, try alternate solver, try 1 pF across each diode, try 1 Mohm across each diode, try 1 mohm series resistance from your voltage source.